# In relay, how can I get the outputFilelds defined in graphql?

Tags: graphql, relay

I am learning graphql/relay by reading the todo sample.

The mutation schema was defined as below:

```
const GraphQLChangeTodoStatusMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'ChangeTodoStatus',
  inputFields: {
    complete: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLBoolean) },
    id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
  },
  outputFields: {
    todo: {
      type: GraphQLTodo,
      resolve: ({localTodoId}) => getTodo(localTodoId),
    },
    viewer: {
      type: GraphQLUser,
      resolve: () => getViewer(),
    },
  },
  mutateAndGetPayload: ({id, complete}) => {
    const localTodoId = fromGlobalId(id).id;
    changeTodoStatus(localTodoId, complete);
    return {localTodoId};
  },
});
```

the relay mutation was defined [here](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/examples/todo/js/mutations/ChangeTodoStatusMutation.js), and called like below:

```
this.props.relay.commitUpdate(
  new ChangeTodoStatusMutation({
    complete,
    todo: this.props.todo,
    viewer: this.props.viewer,
  })
);
```

I am just confused about the outputFileds in schmea was never used in caller, and looks non-relevant to fat query in relay. Could anyone please explain this in details?

Anyway, my final goal is to implement authentication in grapahql/relay (like below), which need to get the output defined in mutation schema, but I don't know how to.

```
mutation {
  createToken(username: String!, password: String!) {
    token
    error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the `outputFields` directly, instead of using them to update the client store, you can define `onSuccess` function and access them through `response` object.

```
const onSuccess = response => {
    if (response.createToken.error) {
        console.log('Could not create token. Got error: ' + error);
    } else {
        // store response.createToken.token for future use.
    }
};
this.props.relay.commitUpdate(
    new CreateTokenMutation({username, password}),
    {onSuccess}
);
```

On your client-side mutation implementation i.e. `CreateTokenMutation`, you have to specify that the `outputFields` are not meant to update the client store. So, you'll use `REQUIRED_CHILDREN` mutator configuration.

```
class CreateTokenMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation {createToken}`;
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
        username: this.props.username,
        password: this.props.password,
    };
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on CreateTokenPayload @relay(pattern: true) {
        token,
        error,
      }
    `;
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: REQUIRED_CHILDREN,
      children: [
        Relay.QL`
          fragment on CreateTokenPayload {
            token,
            error,
          }
        `,
      ],
    }];
  }
}
```

To know more about it, check [Relay documentation on mutation](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html#required-children).